# Growth of Digamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, gamma-function, riemann-zeta, digamma-function

> For $1\le \sigma \le 2$ and $t\ge 2$, $s=\sigma+it$ prove that $\displaystyle \frac{\Gamma'(s)}{\Gamma(s)}=O(\log t)$.

From Stirling's formula we have, $\displaystyle \Gamma(s)\approx \sqrt{2\pi}\exp\{s\log s-s-\frac 12 \log s\}$.

Then, $\displaystyle \frac{\Gamma'(s)}{\Gamma(s)}\approx\log s-\frac{1}{2s}$. From here I'm unable to estimate !! Any hint. ?

Where can I get rigorous proof ?

**Edit:** Wikipedia links below the question are NOT clear enough to me.

Comment: See [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)

Comment: Stirling's approximation is literally an approximation, which you cannot differentiate to derive asymptotic formula for $\Gamma'(s)/\Gamma(s)$. (For instance, differentiating both sides of $\sin(e^x)=\mathcal{O}(1)$ leads to nothing.) In this case, the series representation of the [*digamma function*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) would help.

Comment: @SangchulLee But in my book it is written that "from Stirling's approximation we can get...." the above expression..!!

Comment: As pointed out above differentiating asymptotics is problematic in general (as small oscillations affect the derivative, but not as much the function value), but it usually works for cases where the function is monotonic like here (though making it rigorous is probably not straight forward)

Comment: @Winther For your 1st comment, here $s$ is not real..

Comment: Ah ok, I missed that. Then I don't see how one can argue for using Stirlings here. I would follow the links given above and try to do a more rigorous estimation of the growth.

Comment: @lhf I've seen it. But how can I calculate the growth of Digamma function? Any reference or any book ?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Computation_and_approximation

Comment: Differentiating the Striling approximation directly is not allowed, all you can do is using the Cauchy integral formula to obtain $F(s) = O(G(s)) \implies F'(s) = O(G(s))$. The good approximation of $\Gamma'/\Gamma$ follows from its explicit formula $-\gamma+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{s+n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$,  $(\Gamma'/\Gamma)' = \ldots$

Answer (score 4):

If you need to differentiate a holomorphic function, try to integrate instead.

Let $g(s)=\log\sqrt{2\pi}+s\log s-s-\tfrac12\log s$; so $\log\Gamma(s)=g(s)+o(1)$.

Take a circle around $s$ with radius $r=\frac12$. By Cauchy's formulas,
$$
\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}(s) = g'(s) + \big(\log\Gamma(s)-g(s)\big)' =
\log s-\frac1{2s} + \frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|w-s|=r} \frac{\log\Gamma(w)-g(w)}{(w-s)^2} \mathrm dw;
$$
$$
\bigg|\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}(s) - \log s+\frac1{2s} \bigg| \le
\frac1{2\pi}\oint_{|w-s|=r} \frac{\big|\log\Gamma(w)-g(w)\big|}{r^2} |\mathrm dw|
\le O(1)
$$
so, 
$$
\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}(s) = \log s + O(1).
$$

Comment: How, $\log \Gamma (s)=g(s)+O(1)$ ? It will be $g(s)+O(1/s)$

Comment: $|s|\ge\sigma>1$

Comment: How $\log s+O(1)=O(\log t)$ ?

Comment: You should clarify your own question. Is $\sigma$ fixed or it varies? What is the range of $t$?

Comment: $1\le \sigma \le 2$ and $t\ge 2$.

Comment: $\log s-\log t = \log\left(\frac\sigma{t}+i\right)=O(1)$.

Comment: I'm not getting why $\log (\sigma /t+i)=O(1)$ ?
$\log (\sigma /t+i)==\frac 12 \log (\sigma^2/t^2+1)+i \arctan(t/\sigma)$. How you estimate this to get $O(1)$ ?

Comment: O(1) means bounded. Both the real and the imaginary parts are bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use the following formula, from Abramowitz and Stegun, valid everywhere in the strip of interest:
$$
\psi(z)=-\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z-1}{n(n+z-1)}.
$$

Letting $a=\sigma-1\in[0,1]$,
$$
\psi(\sigma+it)+\gamma=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a+it}{n(n+a+it)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(a+it\right)(n+a-it)}{n\left((n+a)^2+t^2\right)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a(n+a)+int+t^2}{n\left((n+a)^2+t^2\right)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a(n+a)}{n\left((n+a)^2+t^2\right)}+i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{t}{(n+a)^2+t^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^2}{n\left((n+a)^2 + t^2\right)}.
$$
The first term is no more than $2a\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^2=\pi^2/3$, independent of $t$.  The second and third terms can be bounded by integrals; the third integral must be split into two sums first.  Specifically,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{t}{(n+a)^2+t^2}\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1/t}{(n/t)^2+1}\le\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2+1}=\frac{\pi}{2},
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=t+1}^{\infty}\frac{t^2}{n\left((n+a)^2+t^2\right)}\le \sum_{n=t+1}^{\infty}\frac{1/t}{(n/t)\left((n/t)^2+1\right)}\le\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x(x^2+1)}=\log\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)\Bigg\vert_{1}^{\infty}=\frac{1}{2}\log 2.
$$
Note the restricted range of summation.  Finally,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{t}\frac{t^2}{n\left((n+a)^2+t^2\right)}\le\sum_{n=1}^{t}\frac{1}{n}=O(\log t),
$$
so we conclude that $\psi(\sigma+it)$ is $O(\log t)$, with bounded imaginary part.

Comment: How you estimate the 1st term is no more than $\displaystyle 2a\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ ?

Comment: @Empty: Because $a\in[0,1]$, $(n+a)/n \le (n+1)/n \le 2.$

Comment: How you got $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1/t}{(n/t)^2+1}\le\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2+1}$ ?

Comment: @Topo: Draw the (decreasing) curve $1/(x^2+1)$.  Make vertical ticks from the $x$-axis to the curve at $x=1/t$, $x=2/t$, etc., and connect each to the vertical tick/axis to its left.  You've drawn an infinite family of rectangles under the curve; the sum of their areas (the left-hand side) is less than the area under the curve (the right-hand side).